Yank to char using avy including the selected character
I want to be able to yank the text to char including the character using avy. For this I wrote the following command:
(defun my/yank-to-char-avy ()
  "Delete region from point to a character."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (set-mark (point))
    (evil-avy-goto-char-in-line)
;; (evil-forward-char)
    (evil-yank (mark) (point) )
    (deactivate-mark)))

The problem with this is that it yanks up to char, but not the char including. How can I change the script, so I include the character selected. It seems I need to change the point to the next character.
But I don't know how to put in point+1. It would also be useful for some other commands I would like to implement.

why doesn't (forward-char) work?

Good question. When you yank backwards, that is to the left of the cursor the selected character isn't included.
